# After getElementById, getElementByClass doesnt link to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have problem with weird behaviour in JavaScript that I don't understand:

If I get element (for example a row in table) like this:

```
var someElement = document.getElementById("row1");
```

And then try to find element by class from that element (column for example) and change the innerHTML, nothing happens:

```
someElement.getElementsByClassName("column1").innerHTML = "new text";
```

But if I instead do this:

```
someElement.childNodes[0].innerHTML= "new text";
```

The elements innerHTML changes and is visible on the DOM. Why is this happening like this? I think the class thing would produce cleaner code for me right now, so is there a way to get the class method to work as I think it should?

I'm using the newest version of Chrome.

Comment: show your code here

Answer (score 2):

There is no `getElementByClassName()` should be `getElementsByClassName()` (note the `s` at the end of `elements`.

But the main problem come's when you're trying to call the property of object `innerHTML` on the result of `getElementsByClassName()` that return an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

Anyway I suggest the use of `querySelector()` or `querySelectorAll()` instead like :

```
someElement.querySelector(".column1").innerHTML = "new text";
//Or
someElement.querySelectorAll(".column1")[0].innerHTML = "new text";
```

Else you could just point on the first element of the returned result like :

```
someElement.getElementsByClassName("column1")[0].innerHTML = "new text";
```

Comment: Typo in my original message, I'm going to fix that. I used tab in browser and here there is no tab.

Comment: Ok I see, Updated my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Thing is ID is unique, Class can be used on multiple elements that is why function is called getElementsByClassName, notice the `S` in elements, to change anything with class you must go through loop, so you can use this for example

```
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("example"); 

    for( let i = 0; i< a.length;i++)
         a[i].style.top = "50px";
```

Notice: this is only example, use your innerhtml or whatever you need instead